# Herbrand universe with infinite terms (for a lazy programing language)

Tags: logic, denotational-semantics

I am working with a toy programming language for my thesis.  It is lazy evaluating so I can have infinite terms (for example the "infinite natural number" `inf := S(inf)`).
There is a proof assistant build into my language so I want to write down denotational semantics for it.

Now I want to describe a [Herbrand universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbrand_structure) for this language. But in the literature I have Herbrand structures always deal with finite terms.  The infinite ground term that `inf` should denote is `S(S(S(...)))`.

Can I simply extend the definition of a Herbrand universe to infinite terms? Is there any literature for such a thing (I did not yet find any)?  Are there any pitfalls I have to be aware of?

Comment: You might want to look up terms "syntactic category" and "syntactic model", as those are modern incarnation of Herbrand models. They are used in programming language theory and logic. Do we get to see your language? Does it have any computational side-effects? Non-terminating expressions?

Comment: The syntactic model consists of the actual terms of the language. The terms of your language are presumably finite. So why do you say they're infinite? Are you trying to use normal forms or values to build a model?

Comment: note that the language doesn't need to be lazy evaluating for you to have that kind of feature, in ocaml (which is eager), you can type `let rec inf = S inf` (because the constructor boxes the value).

Comment: The code for the project is at https://github.com/lucc/ulang-tiny , it was started by my professor and part of my thesis is to underpin it with some theory (so I don't really care if the language needs to be lazy, it just is). Sadly there is no documentation (apart from comments and commit messages). The language has no side effects apart from reading the source file and printing to stdout. Thanks for the keywords, I will look them up.